# How to have left and right arrow above and below with an equation with text

Tags: math-mode

I want to know how I can write an equation that has a left arrow on top with text and a right arrow on the bottom with text. Essentially, I want to be able to write:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Due to the symmetry, an `array` will do with no other trick:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{dI}{dm}=
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
\text{Approach 1} \\
$\leftarrowfill$\\
\displaystyle
\frac{\partial f_p(m_{p})}{m_{p}}\,
\frac{\partial f_{p-1}(m_{p-1})}{m_{p-1}}
\dots
\frac{\partial f_1(m_{1})}{m_{1}}
\\
$\rightarrowfill$\\
\text{Approach 2}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

For less generous vertical space use something like

```latex
\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.75}
\frac{dI}{dm}=
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
\text{Approach 1} \\
$\leftarrowfill$\\
[...]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect!